# Change to Application.Calculation xlAutomatic without re-calculating

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA in which I first turn of the calculation in the Excel sheet using `xlManual`. 
Afte rhte procedure is done it is switched back to `xl.Automatic`.

```
Sub Run_Procedure()
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Call Procedure
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

All this works as it should

---

Now, I am wondering if there is a way to change the application to `xlAutomatic` without actually `re-calculating` the file.

Basically, I just want that once the `procedure` is done the `User` can continue working with the file normally. 
To avoid loading time after the `procedure` it should not calculate again.

Do you have any idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but the only way I can think of is to use `Application.CalculationInterruptKey` and `Application.SendKeys()`.

Perhaps something like...

```
With Application
    .CalculationInterruptKey = xlEscKey
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .SendKeys ("{esc}")
    Debug.Print .CalculationState
End With
```

From what I've read this will interrupt the sheet recalculation by sending the `esc` key press to the application but I've not been able to confirm it works (as I don't have any large enough data that takes some time to calculate.

On a side note, if you want to return the `CalculatonInterruptKey` back to it's original value, just assign a variable it's value before the above code, then after the code assign the variable back to the property.